# Why does it take long time for the whole CI-CD process to complete?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, devops, google-cloud-build

I am following a CI-CD process for my node application. I am able to deploy it successfully, but the problem is it is taking a very long time for the whole process. How can I make this CI-CD process faster ?

Below is my cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
steps:
    # Install npm
    - name: 'node:10.10.0'
      args: ['npm', 'install']
      dir: './UI'

    # Make the app prettier
    - name: 'node:10.13.0'
      entrypoint: bash
      args: ['-c', 'npx prettier --check "**/*"']
      dir: './UI'

    # Execute the lint command
    - name: 'node:10.10.0'
      args: ['npm', 'run', 'lint']
      dir: './UI'

    # Install Phantom JS -g karma-cli
    - name: 'node:10.10.0'
      args: ['npm', 'install', '--save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher']
      dir: './UI'

    # NPM test
    - name: 'node:10.10.0'
      args: ['npm', 'run', 'test']
      dir: './UI'

    # Build dev file
    - name: 'node:10.10.0'
      args: ['npm', 'run', 'build_dev']
      dir: './UI'
      timeout: 1800s

    # List the files in the UI directory
    - name: 'node:10.10.0'
      entrypoint: bash
      args: ['-c', 'ls -la']
      dir: './UI'

    # Deploy UI build to CS-D Portal
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
      args: ['app', 'deploy', './']
      dir: './UI'

timeout: 1801s
```

This process is taking me more than `15 minutes` which is too much I think. How can I make it to run `prettier, linting and unit tests` to run all at once and not sequentially ?

Edit_1:

```
steps:
        - name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
          args:
          - --destination=gcr.io/xoxoxoxoxo/node:10.13.0
          - --cache=true
          - --cache-ttl=48h

        # Install npm
        - name: 'node:10.13.0'
          args: ['npm', 'install']
          dir: './UI'
    
        # Make the app prettier
        - name: 'node:10.13.0'
          entrypoint: bash
          args: ['-c', 'npx prettier --check "**/*"']
          dir: './UI'
    
        # Execute the lint command
        - name: 'node:10.13.0'
          args: ['npm', 'run', 'lint']
          dir: './UI'
    
        # Install Phantom JS -g karma-cli
        - name: 'node:10.13.0'
          args: ['npm', 'install', '--save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher']
          dir: './UI'
    
        # NPM test
        - name: 'node:10.13.0'
          args: ['npm', 'run', 'test']
          dir: './UI'
    
        # Build dev file
        - name: 'node:10.13.0'
          args: ['npm', 'run', 'build_dev']
          dir: './UI'
          timeout: 1800s
    
        # List the files in the UI directory
        - name: 'node:10.13.0'
          entrypoint: bash
          args: ['-c', 'ls -la']
          dir: './UI'
    
        # Deploy UI build to CS-D Portal
        - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
          args: ['app', 'deploy', './']
          dir: './UI'
    
    timeout: 1801s
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that running the 3 stuffs in a row into the same step will help you to save time, few seconds not more.

You have here some tips to speed up your process.

- Use the same image for all the steps, that prevent Cloud Build to download different ones. *Example: your `prettier` step, not the same at the others*
- Use Kaniko cache to cache the images, that prevent to download the image at the first step, it's immediately in cache
- Increase the number of CPU. You will increase the processing performances **AND the internet bandwidth allowed to your job**. Your image pulling and your dependencies downloading will be quicker.

Google provides tips [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Please check my `Edit_1` section and tell me if this is the correct way to write.

Comment: Yes, it's correct but by reviewing your build step, it will be useless. Kaniko cache is efficient when you build container, and here you don't build one :(

Comment: So, what would you suggest me to do ?

Comment: You have fixed the multiple image pulling, now you have only one. Kaniko is useless, you can [increase the size of the Cloud Build VM](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds#using_custom_virtual_machine_sizes).